# change color of menu depending on background

Tags: css

I'm using `mix-blend-mode` to change the color of my hamburger menu but it isn't working. The menu stays the some color regardless of what the background is. Here's the CSS and HTML

```css
:root {
--black-color: #3F3D3C;
--white-color: #FAF9F6;
--taupe-color: #D8C7B8;
--grey-color: #CCC5C2;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 5%;
  max-width: 25px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.menu .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu .icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

.menu .icon>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5px;
  background: var(--black-color);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.menu .icon>div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.menu .icon>div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.black {
background-color: var(--black-color);
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

.grey {
background-color: var(--grey-color);
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

.white {
background-color: var(--white-color);
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.opacity='1'">

  <div class="icon">
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="overlayHidden" id="overlay">

    <nav>
      <div id="nav-links"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="white">content with different background color</div>

<div class="black">content with different background color</div>

<div class="grey">content with different background color</div>
```

where am I going wrong?

EDIT:
updated the code so you can run snippet

Comment: Could you check your snippet - there's a color variable not set I think and also there is no means of scrolling to get different backgrounds.

Comment: @AHaworth I updated the code so that the snippet will work